# Pulling credit memo from database using MySQL query

Tags: magento-1.9, database, query

I'm trying to pull a credit memo from the directly from the database but i keep getting the below error

ERROR:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM sales_flat_creditmemo as o LEFT JOIN
>   sales_flat_creditmemo_grid AS i ON i.`' at line 1

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    o.`increment_id` as `Credit Memo #`, 
    CONCAT(YEAR(o.`created_at`), '/', LEFT(MONTHNAME(o.`created_at`),3), '/', DAY(o.`created_at`), ' ', TIME(o.`created_at`)) AS 'Created At',
    i.`order_increment_id` as `Order number`,
    CONCAT(YEAR(i.`order_created_at`), '/', LEFT(MONTHNAME(i.`order_created_at`),3), '/', DAY(i.`order_created_at`), ' ', TIME(i.`order_created_at`)) AS 'Order Date',
    i.`billing_name` AS `Bill to Name`,
    j.`sku` AS `SKU`,
    j.`name` as `Description`,
    j.`qty` AS `QTY`,
    j.`price_incl_tax` AS `Item Value(incl)`,
    o.`creditmemo_status` AS `Status`,
FROM sales_flat_creditmemo as o
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_creditmemo_grid AS i ON i.`entity_id` = o.`entity_id`
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_creditmemo_item AS j ON j.`entity_id` = o.`entity_id`
WHERE date(o.`created_at`) >= ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(ADDDATE(now(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND date(o.`created_at`) <= LAST_DAY(ADDDATE(now(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
AND date(i.`order_created_at`) >= ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(ADDDATE(now(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND date(i.`order_created_at`) <= LAST_DAY(ADDDATE(now(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
AND i.`parent_item_id` IS NULL AND state IN ("complete", "processing", "canceled" , "pending_payment")
ORDER BY o.`created_at` DESC
```

Can someone please help where i'm wrong?

PS: using magento 1.9

Answer (score 1):

remove ',' before FROM statement

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147423)

Comment: I found syntax error in query that cause the problem. why it is not an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You had some syntax errors :-)
But also a logic error: sales_flat_creditmemo_grid doesn't have a parent_item_id.

Here is your corrected statement (anyway you have to now, if the columns and conditions are what you need - I'm not sure that everything makes sense in that statement):

```
SELECT o.increment_id as 'Credit Memo #', 
CONCAT(YEAR(o.created_at), '/', LEFT(MONTHNAME(o.created_at),3), '/', DAY(o.created_at), ' ', TIME(o.created_at)) AS 'Created At',
i.order_increment_id as 'Order number', 
CONCAT(YEAR(i.order_created_at), '/', LEFT(MONTHNAME(i.order_created_at),3), '/', DAY(i.order_created_at), ' ', TIME(i.order_created_at)) AS 'Order Date', 
i.billing_name AS 'Bill to Name', 
j.sku AS SKU, j.name as Description, 
j.qty AS QTY, 
j.price_incl_tax AS 'Item Value(incl)', 
o.creditmemo_status AS Status 
FROM sales_flat_creditmemo as o 
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_creditmemo_grid AS i ON i.entity_id = o.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_creditmemo_item AS j ON j.entity_id = o.entity_id 
WHERE date( o.created_at) >= ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(ADDDATE(now(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND date(o.created_at) <= LAST_DAY(ADDDATE(now(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) 
AND date(i.order_created_at) >= ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(ADDDATE(now(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND date(i.order_created_at) <= LAST_DAY(ADDDATE(now(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) 
AND o.state IN ("complete", "processing", "canceled" , "pending_payment") 
ORDER BY o.created_at DESC
```